# Circuitpython and Micropython ethernet http get

Tags: python, http-get, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am working with CircuitPython Libraries on MicroPython using the Raspberry Pi Pico. I am using Wiznett 5500 (ethernet module) and Esp01 (wifi module). When I tried jsonplaceholder's api, Wiznett can get request in 4,5 seconds and ESP01 can get request in 1.6 second. When I tried my real api Wiznett 5500 can get request in 1 minute and Esp01 can get in 1.6 second. My api is really fast like microsecond, I don't understand why is wiznett getting data in 1 minute.

```
import board
import busio
import digitalio
import adafruit_requests as requests
from adafruit_wiznet5k.adafruit_wiznet5k import WIZNET5K
import adafruit_wiznet5k.adafruit_wiznet5k_socket as socket
import gc
from machine import UART,Pin
import time
print("Wiznet5k WebClient Test")
uart = UART(0, rx=Pin(1), tx=Pin(0), baudrate=115200,rxbuf=512)
while True:
    //wiznett's code:
    JSON_URL = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    cs = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.GP13)
    spi_bus = busio.SPI(board.GP10, MOSI=board.GP11, MISO=board.GP12)
    eth = WIZNET5K(spi_bus,cs)
    requests.set_socket(socket, eth)
    print("Fetching json from", JSON_URL)
    r = requests.get(JSON_URL)
    print(r.json())
    r.close()
    gc.collect()
    print("Done!")
    // Esp's code:
    time.sleep(1)
    gc.collect()
    uart.write("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"+"\n")
    gc.collect()
    print(uart.read())
```

Comment: The Wiznet W5500 has a dreadful interface over a very slow connection.  For transfers of any non-trivial size, it will suck.

Comment: It can get data from jsonplaceholder 4,5 second which is fine by me but It is getting in 1 minute from my api. What I want to get with request is {"exampleexa":888.8}. Tim Roberts what do you suggest for ethernet module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get more data not only {"exampleexa":888.8}. Add like 3 more lines.

```
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```